# How to add a Numeric Up / Down control to a .Net StatusStrip container

Tags: visual-studio-2008, statusstrip

I'm looking to add a numeric up / down control to a .Net StatusStrip.  Unfortunately, it isn't listed as an option in the UI designer.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [ToolStripControlHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.aspx) class to host a custom ( NumericUpDown for now ) class.
You can also derive from this class "NumericUpDownToolStripItem" which initialize the "Control" property with the custom control and can populate next properties from the hosted control ( Min, Max, Value - for example ).

Comment: I'll vote you up once I get votes again.  I had already used all mine!

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding 3 ToolStripStatusLabels, set the Image of the first to an "Up Arrow" and the Image of the Third to "Down Arrow".  Blank their Text properties.

The Middle one can hold the Number, which you increase/decrease in the Click Events.

Edit: Left/Right Arrows would probably look better.  Left for Down, Right for Up.